# reset or reload the same page in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to reload the same url in Angular 2 by using `router.navigate` but it is not working.

Url: http://localhost:3000/page1

Scenario: I am on http://localhost:3000/landing and on click of button, will pass routing parameter which should reload the page.

Example:

Suppose user is in page1(Edit form) and url reads as `localhost:3000/page1` and there will be a button Create new, on click of button passing a routing paramter using

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { queryParams: { "refresh": "Y" } }; 
this.router.navigate(['page1'], navigationExtras);
```

Comment: Explain the problem clearly with the code

Comment: Suppose user is in page1(Edit form) and url reads as http://localhost:3000/page1 and there will be a button Create new, on click of button passing a routing paramter using let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
                queryParams: {
                    "refresh": "Y"
                }
            };
            this.router.navigate(['page1'], navigationExtras); . it should call a ngOnInit() method. but it's not

Comment: You should have updated this in the question

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

ngOnInit is only called when the component is created. When you navigate to the same page (with different url parameters) the ngOnInit method is not recalled. You should use the ActivatedRoute Params Observable

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        // this is called everytime the url changes
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `window.location.reload();`